# Hard to kill with an Arrow

Tags: plot-explanation, the-huntsman-winters-war

Yesterday I watched *The Huntsman: Winter's War* (2016).

In this movie there is one particular scene in which the snow queen asked Sara to kill Eric. So Sara shot an arrow that hit Eric; he fainted and looked like he is dead and then Sara and the snow queen left with the army of the snow queen leaving 2 dwarfs and Eric's body.

The dwarfs pull the arrow from Eric's body with difficulty and they do Eric woke up and the dwarfs are stunned by that. Eric looks to his locket suggesting that the locket took most of the force of the hit.

I have several questions about this particular scene.

1. How can Eric survive such an attack? You can see Eric dodge backwards by the impact of the arrow in that scene and immediately faint on the ground.
2. Even if Sara hit the locket intentionally to take most of force of the arrow, how can she manage to hit it in a way that the arrow hit the locket without breaking it into two (or several parts) and also it hit Eric's chest? And in such a way that doesn't kill him. (You can say that arrow hit Eric also as it is still intact to body and the dwarfs use quite a strength to remove it from the body and there is also blood on his chest).
3. Did Sara hit some special spot of his body that makes Eric faint and removing it wakes him up? And in the immediate next scene he looks normal with blood on his chest, smiling and planning with the dwarfs about how to enter the castle like nothing has happened.

Sara never misses but how is she able to execute such a hard task?

Is there something that I am missing or *am I thinking too much and should just watch and enjoy*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The latter. It's typical movie, and fairy tale, plot armor. It only works that way in movies. Well, that and any real life event where a book, bible, badge or locket stops a bullet, Arrow or piece of shrapnel. President Roosevelt is famous for that. But it's mostly dumb luck and not something anyone should rely on.